# How to check PHP version using only syntax checker output

Tags: php, php-7, php-8

I want each member of my team to (reliably) report which version of PHP they are checking their syntax against. Members of my team have various operating systems, IDEs and text editors, with various PHP syntax checker plugins, and multiple `php` executables with different versions. Asking them to run `php -v` for example, might report a different version to what their editor is using for syntax checking.

I began to look at changes to the language syntax between versions, with the idea that I could write a PHP file that will trigger different syntax errors in different versions. For example, in PHP 8.0, `match` is now a reserved keyword. This code is valid in 7.4, and triggers `unexpected token ";"` in 8.0:

```
<?php
$a = match;
```

Is it possible to write a PHP file in such a way that by *just checking its syntax* in a text editor you could deduce the version number of the `php` executable?

Comment: This sounds like me a solution looking for a problem. You're the team leader. You **instruct** your team to use a specific version and they should comply.

Comment: Are they really each working on a different project, with the project dictating the PHP version? Doesn't sound like something a team would do. If you're working towards the same goal, you all need to setup the same environment (project-wise, IDEs/editors and OSs can be the choice of an employee).

Comment: I suppose my real problem is that not all PHP programmers know how to make sure that their dev environment is using the version it should be, and learning how to do that takes some time. I was hoping for something that would save their time by quickly identifying who is on the wrong version. A simple "what syntax errors are in this file" is what I was hoping to send them. And then I could assist those who are on the wrong version.

Comment: I believe focusing your energy on teaching them, even with each of them individually, would yield better results than trying to compensate for their lack of knowledge with a custom made tool. This tool would merely postpone what has to be done - unifying the project syntax. No sense in producing new code at 7.* if the project is at 8.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the points made by @CatchAsCatchCan and @El_Vanja in the comments. All projects should have an agreed PHP version, and all contributors should have the knowledge of how to set their PHP version per project. Also, all changes should be automatically syntax checked by some central build/CI system. If any of these are missing, it is well the investment of time and money to make these happen.

If, before you can reach those goals, you would like an extra tool to help you troubleshoot your editor's PHP syntax checker, I have made this script:

```
<?php

// Check the syntax of this file with whatever tool you normally use
// (for example: your IDE / Sublime Text with a plugin / php -v <filename> )
// Compare the syntax error it reports with the comments below to
// determine which PHP version you have.


// PHP 8.0 will output:
// PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected token ";", expecting "(" in php_syntax_version.php on line 10
$a = match;

// PHP 7.4 will output:
// PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'fn' (T_FN), expecting identifier (T_STRING) in php_syntax_version.php on line 14
class fn{}

// PHP 7.3 will output:
// Parse error: Invalid body indentation level (expecting an indentation level of at least 3) in file on line 19
$str = <<<FOO
abcdefg
   FOO
FOO;

// PHP 7.2 will output:
// PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use 'object' as class name as it is reserved in php_syntax_version.php on line 25
class object{}

// PHP 7.1 will output:
// PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use 'iterable' as class name as it is reserved in php_syntax_version.php on line 29
class iterable{}

// PHP 7.0 AND 5.6 will BOTH output (SEE BELOW):
// No syntax errors detected in php_syntax_version.php


// -------------------------------------------------------
// To tell between 5.6 and 7.0, uncomment these two lines:
// class C {}
// $c =& new C;

// PHP 7.0 will output:
// PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'new' (T_NEW) in php_syntax_version.php on line 39 !! Do not compare on the line number alone, as this can be misleading. !!

// PHP 5.6 will output:
// PHP Deprecated:  Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in php_syntax_version.php on line 39 !! Do not compare on the line number alone, as this can be misleading. !!
```